# Binding to the current item from within the ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to bind the current item to a tag in button from a listview itemsource like this. How do i do it 
Please help

```
<ListView ItemsSource="Assignments">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <Button Tag="{Binding CurrentItem}">

              </Button>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if Assignments is a collection of string then you need

```
<Button Tag="{Binding}">
```

If Assignments is a collection of Assignment where Assignment has a property Name you need

```
<Button Tag="{Binding Name}">
```

Answer (score 5):

If by "current item" you mean the currently selected item:

```
<Button Tag="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
```

If by "current item" you mean the data item being rendered by the template:

```
<Button Tag="{Binding}"/>
```